# JOIN OR SELECT IN SELECT [MYSQL]

Tags: mysql, join, select

please help me to join these two selects:

```
SELECT IFNULL(sum(estimated_hours * t2.man_hour),0) as 
estimated from project_has_tasks t1 left join users t2 
on t1.user_id = t2.id group by project_id

SELECT IFNULL(sum(TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME 
(time_spent),'%k.%i' )* t2.man_hour),0) as time_spent_cost FROM project_has_tasks t1
left join users t2 on t1.user_id = t2.id group
 by project_id
```

Wanna to get:

```
| estimated | time_spent_cost |
_______________________________
| 000000000 |    00000000     |
```

Comment: But then I've got the results in one column

Comment: see the answer below you can merge it to single query as you are using same tables

Answer (score 1):

Simply put them in one query:

```
SELECT IFNULL(sum(estimated_hours * t2.man_hour),0) as 
estimated, IFNULL(sum(TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME 
(time_spent),'%k.%i' )* t2.man_hour),0) as time_spent_cost
from project_has_tasks t1 left join users t2 
on t1.user_id = t2.id group by project_id
```